# Swift : search in array and see if the values of specific parameter is bigger than 2000

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to know how to search in array and look for one parameter (e.g. location) if there are any location that has value 2000 or bigger
print number of locations ( how many rows ) 
thanks

Comment: Add some code of what are you trying to achieve...

Answer (score 1):

Guess it's a filter that you are looking for.

```
print(numberArray.filter({$0 > 1999}).count)
```

Comment: how can i deal with it if it is : PFObject

Comment: Well, maybe you should have stated that in the question. I don't really even know what PFObject is, and can't find any good documentation about it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure What kind of array you are Using:

I suppose you want to get filtered array with a limit i.e. (location > 2000)

**So you can use like this:**

```
   let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "location >= %@", "2000") // location > 2000
   self.fiteredArray =  NSMutableArray(array: self.arrForFilter.filtered(using: predicate));
   print(fiteredArray)
```

**For Enhancement to filter array with two conditions you can use:**

```
 let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(location >= %@) AND (location <= %@)", "1000","20000") // location > 1000 && location < 2000
 let fiteredArray =  NSMutableArray(array: self.arrForFilter.filtered(using: predicate));
 print(fiteredArray)
```